# Import setup module error while deploying to app engine via google cloud sdk

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, anaconda, google-cloud-sdk

I am writing after a lot of searching and trial and error with no luck.

I am trying to deploy a service in app engine.
You might be aware that deploying on app engine is usually practiced a two step process
1.  Deploy on local dev app server
2.  If step 1 succeeds deploy on cloud

My problems are with step 1 when I include third party python libraries such as numpy, sklearn, gcloud etc.

I am trying to deploy a service in local devapp server. When I import numpy or any other third party libraries in my main.py script it throws an error saying unable to find the module.

I am using cloud sdk and have two python distributions, the default python 2.7 and anaconda with python 2.7. When I change the path to look for the modules in anaconda distribution, it fails to find module ‘setup’ required by the cloud sdk.

Is there a way to install the cloud sdk for anaconda distribution ?

Any help/pointers will be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you using a flexible env or standard environment? which command are you using to run your local server?

Comment: the environment was pointing to the standard python27 but I also have anaconda with all the necessary modules. The error about import setup module is after I change the environment variable to look for modules in anaconda distribution. The command I am using is -   `C:\Users\<myusername>\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin>python dev_appserver.py C:\<folder_with_main_and_app_yaml_files>`

Comment: looks like I am supposed to to edit install.bat to set CLOUDSDK_PYTHON="anaconda python". Any idea where I should make this change?

Answer (score 1):

When using app engine python standard environment, you can install pure python 3rd party libs using pip by vendoring them as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_third-party_library).

There are also a [number of libraries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/built-in-libraries-27) included in the `python27` runtime which can be requested using the `libraries` directive in your `app.yaml` as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#requesting_a_library).

If there's a lib which is not pure python (i.e it uses C extensions) that you want to use in your project, and it's not part of this [list](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/built-in-libraries-27), then your only option is to use a [flexible VM](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/). If you want to use anaconda, you should consider [customizing the runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/about-custom-runtimes) for your flexible VM.

Comment: try and silent install anaconda in your `Dockerfile` with the linux commands listed here http://conda.pydata.org/docs/help/silent.html